# aggregate function expected before ( in SELECT with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, aggregate

I have two tables Project and Comptes i want dispalay Project and his chef in one Query

so did like this

```
 Query q=se.createQuery("SELECT p.idpro,p.IdProjet,p.NomProjet,p.DateDeb,p.DateFin,p.nomimg  (SELECT c.Nom,c.Prenom  FROM   Compte u WHERE  u.Id = p.IdChef group by u.id) FROM   Projets p ");

        listPrj=q.list();
         data.setWrappedData(listPrj);
```

but is still  Get Error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: aggregate function expected before ( in SELECT [SELECT p.idpro,p.IdProjet,p.NomProjet,p.DateDeb,p.DateFin,p.nomimg  (SELECT c.Nom,c.Prenom  FROM   com.persistence.Compte u WHERE  u.Id = p.IdChef group by u.id) FROM   com.persistence.Projets p ]
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.SelectParser.token(SelectParser.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClauseParser.token(ClauseParser.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClauseParser.end(ClauseParser.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.PreprocessingParser.end(PreprocessingParser.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.hql.classic.ParserHelper.parse(ParserHelper.java:29)
```

I have no idea how to fix it and

Comment: please read the doc and learn the basics of sql before asking such questions

Comment: @Thomas Ruiz thanks for replay but if u can't help me why u replay and if u have the solution wat is ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An immediate cause of your problem is in the inner query:

```
  SELECT c.Nom,   -- <-- Aggregate (min, max, sum etc.) expected here
         c.Prenom -- <-- Aggregate (min, max, sum etc.) expected here  
    FROM Compte u 
   WHERE u.Id = p.IdChef 
GROUP BY u.id
```

when GROUP BY is used, all fields within SELECT should be either in aggregate function or
in GROUP BY

The query itself is very cumbersome, something like that, IMHO, is expected:

```
SELECT p.idpro,
       p.IdProjet,
       p.NomProjet,
       p.DateDeb,
       p.DateFin,
       p.nomimg,
       c.Nom,
       c.Prenom
  FROM Compte c,
       Projets p
 WHERE (c.Id = p.IdChef)
```

Comment: now i get this error `unindexed collection before []: projets1_.idchef`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko . . . I, for one, think it is bad form to give answers using old-style join syntax.  You should use `join` and `on` for such a query.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko Thanks it's work for me, i do some changes and it's cool.
`SELECT p.idpro, p.IdProjet, p.NomProjet, p.DateDeb, p.DateFin, p.nomimg,  c.Nom, c.Prenom FROM Compte as c, Projets as p WHERE (c.id=p.IdChef)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query formatted so I can read it:

```
SELECT p.idpro, p.IdProjet, p.NomProjet, p.DateDeb, p.DateFin, p.nomimg 
      (SELECT c.Nom, c.Prenom 
       FROM   Compte u
       WHERE  u.Id = p.IdChef
       group by u.id
      )
FROM   Projets p
```

The first column you have is a lack of comma before the subquery.  Also, you use the table reference `c` in the `select` clause, but it is never defined.  Let's assume the comma is there and `u` should be `c` (abbreviations for table aliases are a good thing).

Your subquery is aggregating on `u.id`; the select statement is by `c.nom, c.prenom`.  This is generating the error.  In most versions of SQL (MySQL being a major exception), all columns in an aggregation query have to be in the `group by` or in aggregation functions.

Also, the `group by` is not necessary, because you are already restricting it to one value.  Here is a fix using `limit`:

```
SELECT p.idpro, p.IdProjet, p.NomProjet, p.DateDeb, p.DateFin, p.nomimg,
      (SELECT c.Nom, c.Prenom 
       FROM   Compte c
       WHERE  c.Id = p.IdChef
       limit 1
      )
FROM   Projets p
```

EDIT:

I miseed that the subquery returns TWO values.  This isn't allowed in a nested `select` statement.  To include the names, just use a regular join:

```
SELECT p.idpro, p.IdProjet, p.NomProjet, p.DateDeb, p.DateFin, p.nomimg, c.Nom, c.Prenom
 FROM   Projets p left outer join
       Compte c
       on  c.Id = p.IdChef
```

Comment: thanks for help and for the explanation but still get the same error

Comment: @user2420469 . . . There is no aggregation, implicit or otherwise, in this query.  Are you sure this is the complete query?  If you have an aggregation function anywhere (`min()`, max()`, etc), then that would change the logic.  Do the results change if you put the subquery in a `max()`?

Comment: i have two tables Projets and Compte and i want display for all the projets his Chef and the same Chef can have more then 1 projet

Comment: @user2420469 . . . I missed one of the problems in the query.  The subquery is returning two values, not one.  Not allowed in a nested select.  Just use a regular join.

Comment: when i use regular join it return this error : `outer or full join must be followed by path expression`

Comment: @user2420469 . . .  I would suggest that you go down the route of fixing this problem.  I don't know Hibernate well enough to fix it, but searching for this error on Google yields many results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.idpro,p.IdProjet,p.NomProjet,p.DateDeb,p.DateFin,p.nomimg,c.Nom,c.Prenom
from projects p,Compte c
where c.Id=p-IdChef
group by c.uid
```

Comment: . . I, for one, think it is bad form to give answers using old-style join syntax. You should use join and on for such a query.